# cardinality violation and NullPointerException while populating a combobox with available courses

Tags: java, sql, combobox, nullpointerexception, cardinality

I am relativity new to java programming any way here what i am trying to do

I am trying to populate combobox1(Add list) with the courses available to the student and then removing the selected item and sending to combobox2(drop list)

but its simply not reacting right especially when the student doesn't have any courses that are available to add and it returns the exceptions
"net.ucanaccess.jdbc.ucanaccessSQLException:cardinality violation"
&
"java.lang.NullPointerException"

here's how initialize each of the comboboxes

```
try 
    {String mail=Login.user_mail;            

        String sql = "select CourseCode from Course where CourseCode!=(select CourseCode from CourseStudent where StudentEmail='"+mail+"') OR NOT EXISTS(select CourseCode from CourseStudent where StudentEmail='"+mail+"')";
        java.sql.ResultSet rs = dbm.select(sql);
        DefaultComboBoxModel  m = new DefaultComboBoxModel();

        while (rs.next()) {
            m.addElement(rs.getObject(1).toString());
            }
            jComboBox1.setModel(m);

        }

        catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());

                }
```

then combo box2

```
     String mail=Login.user_mail;
        String sql = "select CourseCode from CourseStudent where StudentEmail='"+mail+"'";
        java.sql.ResultSet rs = dbm.select(sql);
        DefaultComboBoxModel  m = new DefaultComboBoxModel();

        while (rs.next()) {
            m.addElement(rs.getObject(1).toString());
            }
            jComboBox2.setModel(m);

        }
```

this is within the Add button

```
String ID = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    String mail=Login.user_mail;

            try {
                dbm.insert(" insert into CourseStudent (StudentEmail, CourseCode ) values ('"+mail+"', '"+ID+"') ");

                                    jComboBox2.addItem(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
                                    jComboBox1.removeItem(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
            }  catch (Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insertion Faild\n"+ex);   
    }
```

and this is with the drop button

```
try {
                    String ID = (String) jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();
                    String mail=Login.user_mail;
                dbm.delete("delete from CourseStudent where CourseCode='"+ID+"' And StudentEmail='"+mail+"'");
                jComboBox1.addItem(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem());
                                    jComboBox2.removeItem(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem());
            } catch (Exception e) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Delete Faild\n"+e); 
            }
```

i think the problem lays in the combobox1 SQl statement but i really can't see any other way to do it as i need to retrieve the courses from a table while making sure that the user doesn't take it already from another table...

any help would be greatly appreciated as i said i have been using java for a couple of weeks now and i haven't used sql before so i am a little lost

Comment: Check your user credentials you are using to connect the database

Comment: I save the usermail(the primary key in the user's table) as a static variable in login that use it through the entire project as login.user_mail and i checked that the login is functioning correctly

Comment: The username/password which is used to establish the connection with the database, which is the issue you are having

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cardinality violation when using a subquery that returns two values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608920/cardinality-violation-when-using-a-subquery-that-returns-two-values)